# using __iter__ and __next__ to create my own class

Tags: python, class, iterator

I'm trying to create my own class for an iterator and found such an example:

```
class OddNum:
  """Class to implement iterator protocol"""

  def __init__(self, num = 0):
    self.num = num

  def __iter__(self):
    self.x = 1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.x <= self.num:
      odd_num = self.x
      self.x += 2
      return odd_num
    else:
      raise StopIteration

for num in OddNum(10):
  print(num)
```

the output is: `1 3 5 7 9`

Now, if I remove the row `odd_num = self.x` and change `return odd_num` to `return self.x`, I get the following output: `3 5 7 9 11`

What is the difference between the 2 codes, why should I define a variable to `self.x`?

Comment: You are taking the value of `self.x` from after adding on 2 rather than before doing so. So the difference is 2.

Comment: You increment `self.x` before you have a chance to return the initial value.

Comment: If you want to do that, initialize `self.x = -1`, so that `self.x += 2` produces the first odd number.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, what is happening is that you want to return the value of `self.x` from somewhere in the middle of the `__next__` method, before you increment the value of `self.x` ready for the next iteration.  Therefore the variable `odd_num` is used to hold this value.  If instead you return `self.x` after the `self.x += 2` statement (i.e. add on 2), then you will get a different answer, as you saw.

Another possibility for you to consider is, instead of writing your own class, to implement the iterator using a generator function, if what you want to do is use the value of some variable from somewhere in the middle of the code.  This is because you can put a `yield` statement wherever you like.  So in this example, it would look something like this:

```
def odd_num(num=0):
    x = 1
    while x <= num:
        yield x
        x += 2
  
    
for num in odd_num(10):
    print(num)
```

This gives:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

(Note the `while` in place of the `if` that you had in your `__next__` method.)

Here, the `yield` statement is before the `x += 2` statement, which is not something that could be done using `return` from a method (function).  So there is no need to save the value in another variable to use later.

Comment: I had no idea you posted when I updated my answer. Deleted my nearly identical answer. Nice work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist BTW, don't feel you _have_ to delete your answer. Given the very close timings, nobody could reasonably accuse you of simply copying what I wrote.

Comment: I deleted it because our content was so nearly identical, I felt that one of us should, and I happened to like your phrasing a little better.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Another question from my side: In my example, why is the self.x = 1 is given within the iter function? Why not outside (for example as a class object attribute or before the if statement in the next function)?

Comment: @rodny9 The point there is that you can generate an iterator from the class multiple times. Try doing the following in the calling code: `nums = OddNum(10)` followed by `for n in nums: print(n)` and then again: `for n in nums: print(n)` -- it will work because `nums.__iter__` is called to generate the iterator when the `for` statement is executed. Now try moving the `self.x = 1` into `__init__` instead of `__iter__` and you should see that you can iterate once, but the second time you try to iterate, the iterator is already exhausted and you don't get any more values out.